# ttf2ufm: command not found

Tags: command, tcpdf

I'm trying to install a font for use with TCPDF. To do so, I need to run the included command line utility ttf2ufm. (Included with TCPDF in fonts/utils/ttf2ufm) When I run it though, I get the error -bash: ttf2ufm: command not found. I'm probably just overlooking something simple, but I've searched and can't find what I'm missing here.

Should mention I'm using Debian Lenny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you do not know how commands are executed in bash.

If the program is not in the path, you need to specify the path to get it to run.

If you are in the right directory.

```
.../fonts/utils/ $ ./ttf2ufm ....
```

Note the `./` in front of it, that gives the file a path, in the present working directory, or the full path will work, or any other relative path.  Just using `ttf2ufm` on its own will not, as the current directory is not usually part of the executable path.

Additionally, the program will need its executable bit set.

Comment: Boy do I feel foolish... guess I've been in Windows for too long. ;)

Comment: @chrisSC: Quite alright, the execution method isn't really altogether intuitive.  Took me a while to get used to it, coming from a M$ background to Linux about 13 years ago.